# Creating custom template in Android Studio

Tags: android, templates, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to add a custom template to Android Studio. 
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Android Studio 1.2.1.1.

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/kanytu/Android-studio-material-template), I am adding the template directory to the activities path, but the custom template is not showing in the templates list.

Tried restarting Android Studio too, no success.

Can anyone help me?
I am doing this for first time so need some help.

Comment: Did you follow the TODO guide from here? http://androidshenanigans.blogspot.pt/2015/03/material-design-template.html

Comment: Yes, I followed that too but studio is not showing the template.

Comment: Did you try the menu under **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart**?

Comment: Did you change the name in template.xml?

Comment: I tried restarting and changing name in template file. Nothing works.

Comment: So your `{Android_Studio_Path}/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities/` has a directory for that material activity. That folder has a template.xml where the root `template` tag has a `name` that value? Did you add the folder `Android-studio-material-template-master` to templates or `MaterialNavigationDrawerActivity`?

Comment: I added MaterialNavigationDrawerActivity directory to templates directory.

Comment: And you completely exit/kill Android Studio? When you re-open the app, start new project, you don't see it in the Add an activity? Screen? What are you targeting for devices? What's the min SDK? Are you sure you only have one installation of Studio and that's the path you're editing and executing?

Comment: @SureshKumar I have absolutely the same problem as you. Didn't you find any workaround?

Comment: @saturov Which OS you are working on?

Comment: @SureshKumar Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Where you have placed your android-studio? In my case I had two android-studio folders, so had the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on *Linux Mint 17, Android Studio 2.2 beta*. After some testing I found out that the name in `template.xml` must be unique from the rest of the activity templates. So if you copy the EmptyActivity folder, open `template.xml` and change the name:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<template

    name="Unique Name"
```